# Is it possible to set up wifi hotspot on an ubuntu machine?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hot-spot

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Is it possible to set up wifi hotspot from my machine so that I can use internet on my mobile devices?

It may be noted that I am using laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only if you are using wired Internet connection on you Ubuntu machine.

See

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

for more details.